NavigationList not working in NavigationStack
I have two simple modules in my Swift program.  One maintains a list of Locations and the second maintains a list of Activities.  The locations module works fine while the Activities module freezes!  I can't select any of the listed activities, etc. The code for these two modules is "identical" what am I doing wrong?
The location module contains the following body:
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            if locations.isEmpty {
                ContentUnavailableView("Enter the first location", systemImage: "location")
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(locations) {location in
                        NavigationLink {
                            EditLocationView(location: location)
                        } label: {
                            Text(location.name)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        indexSet.forEach { index in
                            let location = locations[index]
                            context.delete(location)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Locations:")
    }

and the activities body is:

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            if activities.isEmpty {
                ContentUnavailableView("Enter the first activity", systemImage: "figure.hiking")
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(activities) {activity in
                        NavigationLink {
                            EditActivityView(activity: activity)
                        } label: {
                            Text(activity.name)
                        }

                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        indexSet.forEach { index in
                            let activity = activities[index]
                            context.delete(activity)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Activities:")
    }

